# Bootstrap progress bar in php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I have got a webpage with some html and php. The php is there to execute some linux commands. I want to put a bootstrap progress bar into my webpage that progresses when the next linux command has been executed.

Let's say I execute 4 linux commands, each time a command has finished executing, the progress bar should progress 25% further.

I have searched the web but I couldn't find anything to what I need. Any suggestions?

Only got the php/html part so far:

```
function progressbarStatus($width) {

    echo "
            <div class = 'container'>

                    <div class = 'progress progress-striped active'>

                            <div class = 'progress-bar' role = 'progressbar' aria-valuenow = '$width' aria-valuemin = '0' aria-valuemax = '100'style = 'width: $width%'></div>

                            </div>

                    </div>

            </div>
            ";

}
```

Comment: Use AJAX requests to see if the commands have been executed and update the width of the bar accordingly. Could you add some code of what you already have?

Comment: The only thing i have is the html part with the progress bar.

Comment: I would either launch a script async that writes it status to some kind of storrage (mysql,memcache,memory,file,etc..) and then create an ajax script to check the status, or look into long polling with an ajax request, if you opt for the long polling be warned that for some browsers you need to do something like echo str_repeat(' ',1024) to kickstart the process.

Comment: Well is there a way that Linux can tell to PHP when the commands have been executed? If not, there's no way to do it properly. How long does the execution of those Linux command take?

Comment: The time differs, but it is around 10 seconds i believe. This actually something I want the progress bar to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to do this and demonstrated here in a very simple format by jQuery;

You will send a AJAX request to your PHP page that has the command, the PHP page will return a `json_encode(array('success'=>true));` and when that's received and accepted, the progressbar updates and the next function will start loading.

I haven't tested this, and it's very rough, but it shows you (in a simple way) a technique that you could use.

```
$.getJSON('linkToLinuxCommand1.php').done(function(data) {
    if (data.success === true) {
        $('.progress').css('width', '25%');
        $.getJSON('linkToLinuxCommand2.php').done(function(data) {
            if (data.success === true) {
                $('.progress').css('width', '50%');
                $.getJSON('linkToLinuxCommand3.php').done(function(data) {
                    if (data.success === true) {
                        $('.progress').css('width', '75%');
                        $.getJSON('linkToLinuxCommand4.php').done(function(data) {
                            if (data.success === true) {
                                $('.progress').css('width', '100%');
                                alert('Done!');
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Some remarks;

- As long as the Linux commands don't talk back to PHP, you only can get the `done` status of the PHP page
- Maybe you need to add more parameters to the `getJSON` request
- I'm not sure if JSON returns a boolean `true` or `false`, so maybe you need to check like a string; `data.success === "true"`
- Keep checking what `data` returns (after you setup your PHP page for returning JSON), using `console.log(data)`
- You might want to bind these functions to a trigger, such as `$('#button').click(function() {/* PLACE HERE */});` and place everything in a recursive function

Comment: Yea I got a button as well, after that the progress bar should start. Thx for the example!

Comment: Could you perhaps take a look at the code i posted below? For testing I created a simple page with a jquery script and a button. It seems that nothing responds..

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on what you need in specific. As you describe it, though, it should be done via ajax. The problem with that is that ajax doesn't allow for responses being delayed, thus you'd have to make ajax calls for every respective task.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ and http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: There are a few points in my php script where I want the progress bar to progress further. I do not necessarily need to check if they have completed, I just want to update the progress bar after the call of a php function.